# Excel multiple criteria sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Please kindly assist with this. I wanted to know if there's a way to write excel formula for this logic. Closing date = y , opening date = x

```
where y <= x
and y +30> x
or y >= x
and x +30> y
or y > x
and x +30<= y
and x <= x
and x +30> x
and x <= x
```

Sample data

[image]

Comment: Your table doesn't have x or y so it's hard to understand the question

Comment: thank you for your response. the x in the table is the start date while y is the end date

Comment: It's still not clear. In November Agent 1 has 1+1 unit sold yet you expect 5 as result

Comment: Yes, there is a way which involves a long, convoluted formula. What have you tried so far? Or even better I'd make aux columns and then make the report witha pivot table.

Comment: the date is rollback. such that -30 days. the aim is to get the sum within every 30 days. So for Nov it will be all sales from oct to nov. In this case the total is from 2019-10-04 to 2019-11-03

Comment: @dmb thanks.. I have tried different sumifs and sumproduct but am getting no where. more to say is that am just not an advance user yet, am just learning and will appreciate your help

Comment: I have tried using aux column to create each of the syntax using "If" function then use pivot but i still doesn't get the desired result .. perhaps am not doing the syntax right

Comment: @dmb Good day.. Please can you offer suggestion on how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it since I write this from my phone, but an sumproduct could work.
Below the cell with "30 day rollback":

```
=Sumproduct((C:C="sals agent 1")*(D:D>(Today()-30))*(F:F))
```

This should sum all sales agent 1 sales units from today and 30 days back.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @andreas however that doesn't work

Comment: @Holu It works... See my image in the answer.

Comment: thank you for your response. The desired result for agent 1 for Nov should be 5. This is because the data have sales Oct and Nov however Agent 1 has sales that are within 30 up to 04/10 to 03/11

Comment: My data is not the same. If you look at my data the correct value should be 2. Since your sales data is in the future TODAY() and 30 days back will obviously not work

Comment: thank you for your response. Unfortunately i still can't get thesame result as you. I tried different current dates but it returned 0

Comment: It's impossible to help you. Your question is lacking details and your comments don't help much. I give up. I have proven it works. If you can't implement the formula to your sheet then it's your fault. If you had posted real data and I could have made a formula that would be just copy paste. But since it's fake data, all responisbillity to implemet the code is on **YOUR** end.

Comment: Hi @andreas. Am sorry if my comment offend you and i really do appreciate the effort you put in to assist. The data is real, the only difference is the date in order to make it anonymous. I can send the file itself with the dates. The months from April - May and the intended result is for May. Sorry once again and appreciate your help